# Word for someone obsessed with improvement and efficiency

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine someone who, in every way, always tries to improve things to make them more efficient.

Therefore, he loves things such as the automation of work because its more efficient. He loves tinkering with things to make them better and hates when things are being done in a certain way when another way exists that would make things faster, clearer, or in some way perform better.

Another example is this person might think the English language should include various proposed punctuation marks such as the irony mark and the authority mark because this would, in his eyes, improve the language. He treats all subjects like this; he always will always look for and advocate for changes in any system to improve it, disregarding traditions or norms as he does so.

I'm not looking for 'perfectionist'; this person doesn't strive necessarily for perfection, but rather sees improvement as an obvious goal that should be worked toward.

Nor am I looking for a word such as determined, motivated, or go getter. I'm looking for a word that focuses on one's obsession for improvement and efficiency.

Any word (noun, verb, or adjective) related to this concept would be appreciated!

Comment: One sense of *perfectionist* is just that: one who constantly keeps improving in pursuit of the perfect result. However, the primary sense dominates.

Comment: **Never** consult a thesaurus when writing your résumé, especially not our local elugameosaurus here.

Answer (score 3):

Innovator

Noun: A person who introduces new methods, ideas, or products.

Copied from https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/innovator

Innovators are always trying to improve things (methods, ideas, and products) and making them more efficient (faster, clearer, and/or better, etc.).

Comment: I like this answer as an innovator is not necessarily a perfectionist

Answer (score 2):

Consider ***optimizer***:

> a person or thing that optimizes
>   <sub>[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/optimizer)</sub>

Where *optimize* means to make things better in various ways.

> to make the most of; develop or realize to the utmost extent; obtain the most efficient or optimum use of
>   <sub>[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/optimize)</sub>